# JavaScript onclick works in browsers, not in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, web, webview, onclick

I have a simple web application, which I'm trying to display through an Android WebView. The webpage consist of not much more than just one HTML table. Each of the cells of said table have an onclick property set to a javascript function, which brings up a box with some information.

This works well in all browsers, both desktop and mobile. However, when I try to click any of the table cells through my Android WebView, nothing happens, the webpage doesn't seem to recognise the clicks.

(Note: I did enable JavaScript for the webview, it does exactly what it should, for example when the document is loaded, only it doesn't recognise the clicks and doesn't fire the corresponding events.)

I've tried searching for an answer, but I had no luck. All threads I found were about solving different problems.

**I'm not trying to run Android code by calling a JavaScript function, I only need the website JS to recognize the clicks.**

What do I have to do to make this work? Thank you very much in advance, and please don't get too upset if my terminology isn't spot on, I'm just a self-taught enthusiast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was using `setOnTouchListener` to handle the WebView clicks and even though I made sure to return false in order to let Android know that the click should be handled further by the WebView, that didn't happen. I believe that could be fixed by calling `super.OnTouchEvent(event)` *somewhere* in the code, but I'm not sure how exactly I'd do that and also I found quite a simple approach that in my opinion makes it way clearer what's actually happening.

The idea is to create a custom "MyWebView" class by extending `WebView` and override the `onTouchEvent` method:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView
{
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    public MyWebView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        this.performClick();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick()
    {
        return super.performClick();
    }

    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        @Override public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
        {
            //do stuff here
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this class please tell me any one??

Comment: I tried to create the class and use it on the activity:
    `<com.academy.MyWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
It was braking, them I just activated the javascript:
       `WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
And the click trigger worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

[image]

**Then in the HTML, call it directly from the button tag:**

[image]

Comment: I don't need to create a JS interface in my Android code. This answer seems to me like it's been copied from the first Google result. I just need to make the `onclick` action work. How do you think your code could possibly work in my case when it still uses `onclick="ok.performClick();"`, the very property that I said didn't work in my example.